# Transform repository data in application or business layer?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am using repository patern in c# with onion architecture containing api, application, domain and data layer.

I noticed that in application layer there is a need for data received from data layer to be in a slightly different format. For example application layer is expecting data from data layer such as

```
GetPeriods()
2017-01-01 2017-01-31 50
2017-02-01 2017-02-28 70
etc
```

But in section of application layer I would also need to get this data in a single day list format such as

```
GetPeriodsAsDays()
2017-01-01 50
2017-01-02 50
etc
```

I want to make sure that I understand both repository pattern and onion architecture correcly, and my question is should I

a) do TransformPeroidsToDays(GetPeriods) in application layer  after I recive data from data layer

or

b) do GetPeriodsAsDays() in data layer and have already formated data at disposition for application layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you want to do `TransformPeroidsToDays(GetPeriods)` in the application layer.  The data layer should only be concerned with creating, retrieving, updating, and deleting (CRUD operations) on raw data.

Transforming the data into something else is "business logic" that belongs in the business logic layer, i.e. what you've called the "application" layer.  I would recommend calling it the former or something other than application layer since it's not commonly called that; the term "application" usually refers to the entire...well...application.

Comment: When you say data layer should be concerned with CRUD operations, I assume you include search operations that could also be an informal data manipulation....

Comment: It's a vast topic with plenty of debate, but I would say no, there wouldn't be much in the way of manipulation of the data in the query.  Just straight queries against entity tables which pull data into POCOs.  This, by the way, makes it possible to use ORM tools like Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Comment: I could agree with that. You say...Makes it possible to use ORM.. Sorry, what makes it possible?

Comment: Having a "conventional" setup, i.e. a db schema with entities that have matching POCOs in your application where you interact with data using pure CRUD ops.